# allways fail when a task instance submit multiple yarn application

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

ds will write all yarn app_ids at table t_ds_task_instance, app_link column.
If is over 255 charters(limit of this varchar column) , mysql driver will throw com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'app_link' at row 1
And treat this task instance as a failure

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kPwY.png)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca039.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should alter app_link's type to longtext，then work well

this bug have fix in dev.
pr: 91ecc54